# Accessing camel Exchange object in OnException block

Tags: apache-camel

```
  .onException(SocketTimeoutException.class,ConnectException.class)
            .handled(true)
            .maximumRedeliveries(5)
            .maximumRedeliveryDelay(5*1000)
```

I want to use exchange object attributes value to configure the maximumRedeliveries and maximumRedeliveryDelay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `retryWhile` on the `onException` to determine if to keep retrying or not. And you can use `Exchange.REDELIVERY_DELAY` as key in a message header to set the delay dynamically.

Comment: I am new to camel, basically what i am looking for is,  when we add any custom processor, we have access to the Exchage object(when we implement the process() method ) available in the route.  Similarly how can i access that exchange object in OnException block.